# How to make Entry select and delete select text?

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter the `Entry` control doesn't allow

- select text by `Ctrl+a`
- if selected by `Shift+->`, however, it still won't allow to  delete it by pressing any key

How to make it behave like any `<input type=text ...` and any other kind of TextBox on desktop, in regards to selecting and then deleting it?

Comment: What you said are allowed in my Python 3.8.16 in Windows 7.

Comment: To add interactive behavior to a widget based on user controls one usually uses the `bind` method on the widget: https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/#using-bind

Comment: @AndrewAllaire the question is "how precisely"

Comment: Indeed, if I had known all the details I would have made an answer rather than a comment. Was trying to get you pointed in the right direction though as there were no answers yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [canonical documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/entry.htm#M65), ctrl+a is defined to move the cursor to the start of the entry and clear the selection. If you instead want it to select everything, you will need to create a custom binding.

The following example shows how to do it for a single entry. It is imperative that the function return the string `"break"` so that any further processing of the event is stopped. Also notice that the function must accept one positional parameter to be given an object that represents the event.

```
def select_all(event):
    event.widget.selection_from(0)
    event.widget.selection_to("end")
    return "break"

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.bind("<Control-a>", select_all)
```

To change the binding for all widgets, you need to understand a little bit about how some default bindings are implemented in the underlying tcl/tk interpreter. Specifically for selecting all of the text, there is a virtual event named `<<SelectAll>>`.  You can associate ctrl+a with that virtual event using the method `event_add`. However, ctrl+a is by default bound to the `<<LineStart>>` virtual event, so you must first disable that binding and then add your own.

```
root.event_delete("<<LineStart>>", "<Control-a>")
root.event_add("<<SelectAll>>", "<Control-a>")
```

Note that because we change the virtual events, this will affect all of the widgets that accept keyboard input, and not just `Entry` widgets.

Comment: Currently if I select a text and then paste a new one, the previous one will remain - along with the new one. How to make it overwrite the existing text?